# Formatting issues with rc2 SDK

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I've got a Rally app that puts two tabs at the top of a window using a tabpanel.  When I upgrade to the rc2 version of the SDK, it tries to match the formatting of the new Rally menus...but unfortunately this looks quite mis-matched with the rest of the app, and it also does not display the entire tab name (it truncates it as "Upcoming R..." instead of "Upcoming Releases").

In general, there are some objects that are in the old style (like an accordion object and the rallybutton) and some that are in the new style (like the tab panel and rallyaddnew).  Unfortunately, all and all it looks rather garish.

What possible remedies are to customize and optimize this new formatting?

[image: New formatting for "Add New" but old formatting for the "Generate Spec" rallybutton]

```
_createTabPanel: function() {
    var curAccord   = this._createAccordian('current');
    var pastAccord  = this._createAccordian('past');

    curAccord.title     = 'Upcoming Releases';
    pastAccord.title    = 'Previous Releases';

    var tabPanelSpec = {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        border: 0,
        forceFit: true,
        minTabWidth: 200 // THIS FIXES THE "tab too small" PROBLEM
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [curAccord, pastAccord]
    };

    return tabPanelSpec;
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a small window of opportunity to release a new sdk version and opted to release 2.0rc2 as-is so customers could begin using it- even though some things (new styling, etc) may not be totally done.  It looks like there are some issues with tab panels from your example above.  We aren't really using these in the product currently, so that makes sense.  Are there other components which are especially bad?

We may be able to offer some small css fixes or ext overrides to get things to look more consistent...

Comment: The issues that I have seen include: * "width" on grid columnCfgs seems to be ignored, * minWidth on tabpanel menus is too small, * a rallybutton that I added to the rallygrid "tools" list is in the old style and color not the new one (like for an Add New button)

Comment: I added a picture of the two format styles for the "Add New" button and a regular rallybutton to the original question above.

Comment: You can fix any buttons by including the following in their configs: componentCls: 'primary small'

Comment: Hmm... that worked when I just added it directly to the app.  What if you do cls rather than componentCls?

Comment: Ok, it did work-- I read it as "CIs" not "CLs", so I had it spelled wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: So with your fix on the button, and by using minTabWidth on tabpanel, the only remaining problem I am aware of is with the 'width' directive on grid columnCfgs seemingly being ignored

Comment: I just debugged the grid column width issue and have verified this is a bug.  Can you post it as a new question so others that may have the same problem can find the solution as well?

Comment: Opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004026/issue-with-rallygrid-column-width-in-rc2

Comment: Actually, one more formatting issue I found: the "accordian" panel is still colored with the old blue theme with rc2-- any short term solution for that?  I tried the componentCls fix to no avail...

Comment: hmm...  again- this is a component we don't really use internally in the product so I doubt we have any styling for it...

Comment: Any way to add styling to match the Rally theme?

Comment: I don't see why not- you'd just have to inspect the element in chrome and figure out what class to override and change the colors. That's all we do when we're styling components.